# Visitor using URL that doesn't exist

Tags: url, query-string

I had someone visit my site today from a link like this:

```
www.example.com/pagename.php?_sm_byp=iVVVMsFFLsqWsDL4
```

Can someone explain to me how that works since my actual URL ends with `pagename.php` and I never allowed a user to input any PHP query and never have session IDs or anything similar.

Comment: do you have anyone linking to your website?  That's a query param that could have been added by whoever linked to your page.   If you're not using that param, it will be ignored.  If you are paying someone to advertise/drive traffic to your site, they could be adding that on the end so you can track how much traffic they are driving to your site.

Comment: Can you get more info from your web server logs?  I'd start by looking at the IP address, user agent, and referrer for all the requests like this.  That might reveal a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This is not unusual. Many sites/servers allow (or rather, *ignore*) arbitrary query components.

For example, you can append `?foo=bar` to those URLs and still get a HTTP status 200:

- https://stackoverflow.com/?foo=bar
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow?foo=bar

Now as they are linked here, users might visit them, so these URLs would appear in their logs. Apart from manually appending such a query component, they might also be added by various scripts, e.g. for [tracking purposes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Tracking), or third-party services that link to your pages (… and [sometimes their origin is unknown](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/37858/17633)).

If you don’t want your URLs to work with arbitrary query components, you can configure your backend/server in such a way that it redirects to the URLs without the query components, or respond with 404, or whatever.

If you keep allowing this, but want to prevent that bots index your URLs with these unnecessary query components, you can specify the canonical variants of your URLs with the [`canonical` link relation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596).